# How to use :onclick and :confirm together in link_to Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, onclick, link-to, confirm

I am trying to hide a `div` on click, after confirmation from the user. 
I have something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'X', user, :method => :delete, :remote => true, :class => 'delete_link', :onclick => "jQuery('#user_#{user.id}').hide();" %>
```

Whenever the 'x' is clicked, I get a confirmation popup, but onclick event is not executed. 

I want to hide the `div` whenever user gives `Yes` in the popup. How do I do this in rails 3 way?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide immediately after click this way.

```
$('.delete-item[data-remote]')
        .data('type', 'html')
        .on('ajax:before', function(event, data) {
            $(this).closest('.item').remove();
        });
```

If you want to wait until the response is back, replace 'ajax:before' with 'ajax:success'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the other way, rather rails 3 way. You can hide your div by having `destroy.js.erb`. and write you div hidding Jquery code there, `#user_#{user.id}').hide();`

Hope, this will help you :)

Comment: I do not want to render anything. Actually am using `render :nothing => true` in the controller action. Moreover am looking for some javascript based solution, which I can reuse throughout my app.